# Windows 7 won't recognize my second hard drive after reinstall

Tags: windows-7

I recently suffered a total hardware crash on my windows C: drive. Fortunately, I had a spare disk on hand and set about reinstalling.

For some reason, during the install it decided to declare my *second* windows drive as the booting drive, but once the installation was completed it completely and utterly refuses to acknowledge the filesystem -- I'm not even seeing a drive letter, while it /does/ find the linux partitions on the other two drives (even if it can't read any of them).

My first (and most important) question: How can I get windows to re-acknowledge the drive, preferably *without* losing all the data on it?

My second question: How can I tell windows to set up its boot loader on the new C: drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to system management - harddrive options(dont remember how it calls correctly) in /administrator and assing letter to your hard drive. ITs common issue after windows reinstall

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the recognizing part. Any suggestions on the second part of my question?

Comment: I'd suggest you to try some of software like paragon partition magic, and probably run chkdks to make sure your harddrive has no errors